# Why is the derivative of $\log ax$, where a is any positive integer, the same?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

For a question in my textbook:

Differentiate $\log(2x)$

The differentiation rule for logarithm is $1/x \ln b$, where $b$ is the base. So my answer was $1/(2x) \ln 10$, but the answer my textbook gave in the back was $1/x \ln 10$. When I substituted $7236x$ for $2x$ in the original equation, the derivative of $\log(7236x)$ is still $1/x \ln b$, not $1/7236x \ln b$. Where did I go wrong? Why is it the way it is?

Comment: Hint: chain rule

Answer (score 5):

The most direct way to attack the problem is to notice that $$\log(cx)=\log(c)+\log(x)$$
and then obviously, on the right side, we have a constant plus $\log(x)$ - and taking the derivative eliminates the constant term. That aside, you used the chain rule incorrectly in your solution, which is why it gets the wrong answer. If we differentiate
$$f(2x)$$
we get
$$2f'(2x)$$
but what you've written is just
$$f'(2x)$$
- that is, you forgot to multiply by the derivative of the inner function $2x$. If $f(x)=\log(x)$, then you correctly wrote out $f'(2x)=\frac{1}{2x}\ln(10)$, but you forgot the factor of two - yielding $$2\cdot \frac{1}{2x}\ln(10)=\frac{1}x\ln(10)$$
which is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the chain rule. For $f(x)=\ln ax$,
$$f'(x)=\frac 1{ax}a=\frac 1x.$$